# How can I use a local docker image in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
RUN apt-get -y update && apt install -y curl
```

In the master node of my Kubernetes cluster I build that image:

```
docker build -t cnginx:v1 .
```

`docker images` shows that the image has been correctly generated:

```
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
cgninx                                     v1                  d3b1b19d069e        39 minutes ago      141MB
```

I use this deployment referencing this custom image:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cnginx
        image: cnginx:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      nodeSelector:
        nodetype: webserver
```

However the image is not found:

```
NAME                                READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-7dd98bd746-lw6tp   0/1       ErrImageNeverPull   0          4s
nginx-deployment-7dd98bd746-szr9n   0/1       ErrImageNeverPull   0          4s
```

Describe pod info:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age              From                Message
  ----     ------                 ----             ----                -------
  Normal   Scheduled              1m               default-scheduler   Successfully assigned nginx-deployment-7dd98bd746-szr9n to kubenode2
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m               kubelet, kubenode2  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-bpbpl"
  Warning  ErrImageNeverPull      9s (x9 over 1m)  kubelet, kubenode2  Container image "cnginx:v1" is not present with pull policy of Never
  Warning  Failed                 9s (x9 over 1m)  kubelet, kubenode2  Error: ErrImageNeverPull
```

I have also tried using the default imagePullPolicy, and some other things such as tagging the image with latest...

So, how can I make Kubernetes use a locally generated docker image?

Comment: You're building on one node and trying to run it on another? Or is this all on the same node?

Comment: The cluster consists of three nodes, one master and two workers. I'm building the image at the master node.

Comment: Right, so as the accepted pointed out that's the problem :p You're building in one place and trying to run it somewhere else (where it doesn't exist).

Comment: Yep, hehe, my bad :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your PODs are scheduled on your worker nodes. Since you set `imagePullPolicy` to `Never` you need to make your image available to both nodes. In other words, you need to build it on both nodes as you did on the master.

As a sidenote, it would be probably easier in the long term if you setup a custom docker registry and push your images there.