# Kubernetes refer docker images from single node and create containers in any node

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Currently I am using an **`external server`** to connect into Kubernetes cluster using a KUBECONFIG file. I have a custom docker image build on this **`external server`(not on master/worker nodes)**.

I need a solution to use this custom image to create a deployment in K8S cluster by using k8s client libraries only (or simply using yaml kubectl create steps)

Is there a way for it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a local docker image in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671576/how-can-i-use-a-local-docker-image-in-kubernetes)

Comment: @joppich: Here I am trying to build the docker image totally outside the `cluster nodes`

Comment: But, if the image is not available in a repo, then it *must* be available on the cluster nodes, how else could a pod be scheduled on them?

Comment: You can, of course, build the image outside the cluster, but unless you run your private image-registry, you are going to have to make it available locally on each node. `docker save <image> | bzip2 | ssh <node> 'bunzip2 | docker load'` might be useful for that.

Comment: @joppich yeah I am aware of docker load. But I would like to accomplish this purely using some APIs without using ssh protocol

Comment: @Ashwin why not pushing it to a registry and then running them from yaml files, like described in the linked case?

Comment: @aurelius I actually have that in the private docker hub repo.